# ExtJS4 #<HTMLDivElement> tags

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I.e. we've got a `#<HTMLDivElement>`:
`<div class=​"cool-class" name=​"2" action=​"someAction" id=​"ext100">button​</div>​`

How can tags' values be accessed?
E.g.

- `someAction` from `action` tag, or
- `2` from `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the HTMLDivElement, for example coolElement, you can try this:

```
    coolElement.attributes['name']
```

and

```
    coolElement.attributes['action'].
```

In case the attribute exists, you can get the value with nodeValue

```
    coolElement.attributes['attribute_name'].nodeValue
```